# Zero divisors of a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> I want to list zero divisors of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/x^3\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.

I know $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ is set of polynomials in one variable whose coefficients from $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

So $x^3\mathbb{Z}_2[x]=\{x^3p(x): p(x)\in \mathbb{Z}_2[x]\}$.

So $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/x^3\mathbb{Z}_2[x]=\{ax^2+bx+c+ x^3\mathbb{Z}_2[x] : a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}_2 \}$

Did i define $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/x^3\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ right?

$x+x^3\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ and $x^2+x^3\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ are the only nonzero zero divisors of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/x^3\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.

Is this correct?

Comment: You described correctly the quotient ring. But what about the residue class of $x+x^2$? Isn't this a zero-divisor? And don't forget $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation is less heavy if you denote, say $\xi=x+x^3\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$, so every element in $R=\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/x^3\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ can be written in a unique way as
$$
a+b\xi+c\xi^2
$$
where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\xi^3=0$.

Certainly $\xi$ and $\xi^2$ are zero divisors, because $\xi\xi^2=0$. But also $(\xi+\xi^2)\xi^2=0$, so you at least forgot to mention one of them.

Let's look when a nonzero $a+b\xi+c\xi^2$ is a zero divisor. It's easy to compute
$$
(a+b\xi+c\xi^2)(u+v\xi+w\xi^2)=au+(bu+av)\xi+(cu+bv+aw)\xi^2
$$
so the product being zero implies $au=0$. Let's first do the case $a=0$, so we get $bu=0$ and $cu+bv=0$. If $b=0$, we need $c\ne0$ and we find $\xi^2$; if $b\ne0$, we need $u=0$ and $v=0$, so we find $\xi$ but also $\xi+\xi^2$.

Suppose $a\ne0$. Then $u=0$ and from $av=0$ we get $v=0$. But then $w=0$: so no luck.

Thus the (nonzero) zero divisors are $\xi,\xi^2,\xi+\xi^2$.